# Updating a column that depends on two other colums all in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a user column and every user have one or more branches(number datatype),the number of branches each user have depends on the currencies he(user) uses(string datatype).
Now i want to change the number of branches by giving it the number of branch the euro currency has but still being dependant on the user .
for example: the user A has 3 branches :

```
123 for euro
145 for usd
489 for gbp
```

after the change i want it to become :

```
123 for euro
123 for usd
123 for gbp
```

I want this change for all users and every user has his own branch number for euro currrency

Comment: This is a really good guide for asking quality questions, and therefore getting quality answers. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ The cliff notes is that you should provide well formatted sample data which is reflective of your table structure along with the expected results. It looks like you provided information here, but frankly it's difficult to follow.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to normalize your data a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written, something like this might work

```
UPDATE Your_Table YT1
   SET YT1.branch = 
         ( SELECT DISTINCT YT2.branch
             FROM Your_Table YT2
            WHERE UPPER(YT2.currency) = 'EURO'
              AND YT1.user = YT2.user
         );
```

If the user has no "euro" record, how do you want that handled?

Comment: every user has euro currency and the columns(user , branch, currency) are in the same table

Comment: @Blue Okay, then this should work from what you've described. Captain Kenpachi actually gave some really good advice up in main comment - just having to write a query like this should make you wary of the design. If you are the one in charge of the table structure normalization would definitely be good to look into.

Comment: Yes but how will i use this since i am working with only one table (account)

Comment: What do you mean? Look at the query again, it only uses one table (yourTable). Just swap out YourTable with Account. You might benefit from reading some articles about correlated subqueries and the different flavors of Update syntax that Oracle supports.

Comment: i don't get the difference between yt1 and yt2

Comment: YT1 and YT2 start off as the same table, just aliased from YourTable. Here YT2 is treated as kind of a dummy copy where we can apply the 'EURO' filter, then use that value to update the main copy YT1. Some DBMS support a more intuitive syntax where this would be written like UPDATE Account AS ACCT_1 FROM (SELECT user, branch FROM Account WHERE currency = 'EURO') AS ACCT_2 SET ACCT_1.branch = ACCT_2.branch WHERE ACCT_1.user = ACCT_2.user;  My answer does the exactly same thing, but works within Oracles syntax constraints.

Comment: Correlated subqueries can be a bit mind bending at first. I highly recommend reading some dedicated articles to get a better understanding.

Comment: Once i run this script all my branch values become null

Comment: String comparisons in Oracle are case sensitive. If your data is in lower case change YT2.currency = 'EURO' to YT2.currency = 'euro' ... or better yet UPPER(YT2.currency) = 'EURO'

Comment: I have this error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: That'll happen if there are multiple 'euro' currency records for a user. Just throw in a distinct and (SELECT DISTINCT YT2.branch) and that should solve that.

Comment: Even if i added distinct i still have the same error

Comment: Ah ... yes it would. If there are multiple distinct branches with 'euro' currency for a given id it doesn't know which one to pick. If we have {User, Branch, Currency} - {1,A,peso}, {1,B,euro}, {1,C,euro} which branch (B or C) do we pick for the update?

Comment: So in that case B or C have the same value , the difference is in an other column that won't affect this request

Comment: That description is unclear. The problem you are having is that there are multiple branches with the same 'euro' currency. Right? Run something SELECT user FROM Account WHERE currency = 'euro' GROUP BY user  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT branch) > 1 . If this returns any records you need to pick which branch the other user id's should be updated with.

Comment: you are right. Can i exclude those users from the past request

Comment: From "past request" I assume that you might have some historical records which are no longer current? If so, if restricting to current records will give you a unique branch per user, then yes, apply that restriction. Note that you'll want to apply it to both YT1 and YT2 to avoid overwriting historical records with current data. Am I understanding your question correctly? In any case, you need to find some way to get a single branch number returned for each user when currency is 'euro'. I don't know your data so I can't really advise on the correct way to do that.

Comment: Are you using "request" and "query" interchangeably? If so, stick with query, it's the more common terminology.

Comment: no i meant the query you wrote:                                                                   UPDATE Your_Table YT1 SET YT1.branch = ( SELECT DISTINCT YT2.branch FROM Your_Table YT2 WHERE UPPER(YT2.currency) = 'EURO' AND YT1.user = YT2.user AND YT2.user NOT IN (SELECT user FROM Account WHERE currency = 'euro' GROUP BY user HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT branch) > 1);

Comment: @Blue We're not making much progress here. Again, you need to be clear about how this scenario should be handled based on your knowledge of the data. You can just pick a random record and that will solve the failure, but it might not be a valid fix based on the meaning of the data. That query I sent was just for profiling so you could see which user record were causing the failure. It wasn't meant to fix the problem. Yes, excluding those offending records will solve the failure, but might not be valid. Please update your question with representative sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Since there is only few users with multiple branches and currency=euro i can make the change i want manually and then exclude them from the query .why it might not be valid ?

Comment: If that works for you that is a perfectly fine approach to resolve the failure. I can't tell you what is or isn't valid, that all depends on your needs. For all I know you need this to work in a live production environment and manual fiddling isn't possible. A lot of times just excluding the records causing problems is a luxury you don't have, you need to work out logic. This is all stuff that depends entirely on your use case.